# How to use recursion to implement "Finding the maximum value in an array" in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, recursion

#### How to use recursion to implement "Finding the maximum value in an array"  in Python ?

The following is a simple test code I wrote

**I want to do it by recursion**

I'm learning algorithms, learning recursion.

Thanks very much!

```
def max(list):
    if list == []:
        msg = "List: ..."    
        return msg

    max = list[0]
    for item in list[1:]:
        if item > max:
            max = item
    return max

data = [8,2,-690,4,12,-320,0, 98]
print(max(data))
```

Comment: What's wrong with the `max()` function?

Comment: Bad idea using `list` as a variable name since it masks the built-in class of that name.  Could you clarify *why* you need recursion for this?  What if the number of elements exceeds python's recursion limit?

Comment: Thank you for the reply
 / I'm learning algorithms, learning recursion.
 / So wanto to use recursion to do practice

Comment: I think you should practice recursion with more valid/logical examples!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use recursion, it's very important to define carefully the end cases.

The maximum of the elements of a list is, obviously, either the first element or the maximum of the rest of the list: it's the greatest of the two values. That's actually the recursion you are looking for.

But what happens when there is no first element? You have an empty list, and an undefined behaviour. Why not `maximum([]) = 0`? Because it would lead to some inconsistency: `maximum([-1]) = greatest(-1, maximum([])) = greatest(-1, 0) = 0`. (You could also try `maximum([]) == -math.inf`, but this won't be very intuitive!)

What if the rest of the list is empty? No problem, you have just one element and it is the maximum.

Just translate this analysis into code:

```
def maximum(xs):
    if len(xs) == 0:
        raise ValueError()
    elif len(xs) == 1:
        return xs[0]
    else:
        u = xs[0]
        v = maximum(xs[1:])
        return u if u >= v else v # greatest(u, v)
```

## More on `maximum([])`

I will try to give a value to `maximum([])`. I repeat the argument above. For any given `n`, `maximum([n]) = greatest(n, maximum([])) = n`. This implies that, for every `n`, `maximum([]) <= n`. The only value that meets this condition is `-math.inf`. Why not define `maximum([]) == -math.inf`? Imagine you create a `minimum` function. For symetrical reasons, you will have to define `minimum([]) == math.inf`. Hence it exists a list `l0 = []` such that `minimum(l0) > maximum(l0)`. No one would accept such a possibility.

What should we do now? There are two main possibilities: defensive programming or use a contract. In defensive programming, the function will check the arguments it has received, and fail if one of these arguments is not correct. That's what I did:

```
def maximum(xs):
    if len(xs) == 0:
           raise ValueError()
    ...
```

If you use a contract, you will basically say: if you give this function an empty list, then the behaviour is undefined. It might return any value, crash, loop forever, .... Here, you would have something like:

```
def maximum(xs):
    """!!! xs must not be empty !!!"""
    ...
```

It seems the same, but there is a huge difference. You can use, *for implementation reasons*, `-math.inf` as the return value for `maximum([])`, because it is now clear that it doesn't have any meaning. Someone who tries to check if `minimum(l0) <= maximum(l0)` for `l0 = []` clearly breaks the contract and won't be surprised by the result. Of course, if you want to make it robust, you will write:

```
def maximum(xs):
    """PRECONDITION: xs must not be empty"""
    assert len(xs) != 0 # can be disabled at runtime at your own risks
    _maximum(xs)

def _maximum(xs):
    """no precondition here"""
    if len(xs) == 0:
        return -math.inf
    else:
        u = xs[0]
        v = _maximum(xs[1:])
        return u if u >= v else v # greatest(u, v)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (using recursion, as requested by the OP):

```
def largest(arr):
    if len(arr) == 2:
        return arr[1] if arr[1] > arr[0] else arr[0]
    else:
        return largest([arr[0], largest(arr[1:])])
```

No built-in functions are used (such as `max`) because the OP has stated that they don't wish to use any built-in functions.

The `else` part of the function `return`s either the first element of the `list` or the largest number in the list (excluding the first element) depending on whichever number is larger.

Each time the `else` part is executed, the `largest(arr[1:])` bit checks which number is largest inside `arr` without the first element. This means that, at one point, `arr` will contain two elements. When it does so, a one-line `if` statement is used to compare the two elements and `return`s the larger element.

Eventually, the code recurses back to the first level and `return`s the largest element.

Answer (score 0):

I would write `max` and `max_all`

```
from math import inf

def max (a, b):
  if a > b:
    return a
  else:
    return b

def max_all (x = -inf, *xs):
  if not xs:
    return x
  else:
    return max (x, max_all (*xs))
```

`max_all` can be called with any number of arguments

```
print (max_all (8, 2, -690, 4, 12, -320, 0, 98))
# 98
```

Or use `*` to [unpack arguments](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists)

```
data = [ 8, 2, -690, 4, 12, -320, 0, 98 ]

print (max_all (*data))
# 98
```

It even works when 0 inputs are given

```
print (max_all ())
# -inf
```

Answer (score -1):

`max` and `list` are [built-in functions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html). So you want to avoid using those identifiers yourself.

Here's a simple version that uses recursion:

```
#/usr/bin/python

def largest(arr):
    if not arr:
        return None
    else:
        r = largest(arr[1:])
        if r > arr[0]:
            return r
        else:
            return arr[0]

data = [8, 2, -690, 4, 12, -320, 0, 98]
print(largest(data))
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply
 / If do not use Python built-in functions (e.g. max) ?
 / I'm practicing the recursion algorithm

Comment: DV because the OP clearly states that they don't want to use any built-in functions

Comment: @Adi219 That requirement was added (via comment) 6 hours *after* I answered. So, no, it was NOT stated anywhere when I answered (contrary to your claim). Neither do I have a time machine nor a mind reading device.

Comment: @Phoenix It's fairly easy to find the maximum of two without using `max`. I have modified the answer as such.

Answer (score -1):

```
def Maximum(list):
    if len(list) == 1:
        return list[0]
    else:
        m = Maximum(list[1:])
         if m > list[0] else list[0]:
              return m
def main():
    list = eval(raw_input(" please enter a list of numbers: "))
    print("the largest number is: ", Maximum(list))
main()

The simplest way
```

Comment: Don't encourage using the name `list` as a variable. Also you have a small indentation error and it would be nice if you explain your answer at least a little bit.

Comment: DV because `list` is used as a variable even though it's a built-in function, the code doesn't compile and because of no explanation (as well as a self-certified claim that this answer is '*the simplest way*')